# Releasing DBContext when using Unity with a class holding the DBContext in a WinForms App

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have an N-Layered WinForms app using Unity for DI.  The startup of the Main is as follows:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IProductRequestRepository, MDIS.DAL.Repositories.Specific.ProductRequestRepository>();
    container.RegisterType<IProductRequestServices, ProductRequestServices>();

    var form = container.Resolve<MdisMain>();

    Application.Run(form);
}
```

IDisposable is implemented in the repository (ProductRequestRepository). An instance of ProductRequestServices class is held by the main WinForm. It is therefor not released unless the app is shut down.  The ProductRequestServices class also has an instance of ProductRequestRepository. The repository is used each time the main window launches a browse Form which uses the repository to get a list of entries using Entity Framework. The repository has an instance of a DBContext it creates when it is instantiated.  I placed breakpoints in the repository implementation Dispose methods but they never get called, probably because the ProductRequestServices object is holding an instance of the repository.

If I add code to manually call Dispose on the repository instance when the browse windows is closed I will get an error when the Browse window is re-opened stating the object is null so I guess Unity does not re-instantiate the object again, only at the start of the application in the composition root.

In this case, should I be re-instantiating my repository class each time the browse window is created to insure the DBContext is new and not with previous content? This is what I am planning to do unless there is something else I can make Unity do.  I can't call Resolve again or any Unity methods once the main form has been opened because my Unity container's scope is limited to the startup main program file I showed earlier. What can I do to address this situation? Thanks in advance.

**** Updated 1/11/2016 9:40pm

For now, the easiest way out of this problem was to remove the Unity container and just wrap the form invocation, which is initiated by a menu option from the main WinForm, in a using statement as shown below:

```
private void detailReportListToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (UnitOfWork aUnitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        ProductRequestServices aProductRequestServices = new ProductRequestServices(aUnitOfWork);
        ProductRequestList aProductRequestList = new ProductRequestList(aProductRequestServices);
        aProductRequestList.ShowDialog();
        aProductRequestList.Close();
    }
}
```

I also removed the DBContext internal instance from my repository and placed it into a UnitOfWork class. The above example allows for my UnitOfWork class to be instantiated with its internal DBContext and passed into the form so it is used on repository calls. When the form is closed the UnitOfWork is released which causes it's Dispose implementation to run and release its DBContext used by the form.  I get a new instance of the DBContext each time the form is opened. When I used the Unity container at the start of the application it held onto a single instance of the ProductRequestServices class instance which caused the problem of not releasing the DBContext. Manually trying to releaswe the DBContext just lead to more problems so this approach will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion to work around this would be:

- Make sure that every time you call some service to do some work, it gets disposed right after it does its work (this needs it not to have a state also).
- Switch dependency injection from constructor arguments to attribute based.

This should make sure that every time your service that does the work with database gets called, it gets a brand new instance of dbcontext.